# Thymeleaf conflict with Reactjs Build

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, create-react-app

I am working on a project that uses ReactJs as frontend and Spring Boot as backend. I would like to pass some environment variables to ReactJS app from backend. My ideas is the following:

1) Use [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) to generate a stub ReactJs application. In the public index.html file, define a customized tag

```html
<body>
    <script th:inline="javascript">
        /*<![CDATA[*/
        var env = [[${env}]];
        /*]]>*/
    </script>
    ...
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

2) Run `npm run build` to generate frontend code

3) Copy generated code from build directory to "resource/templates" directory

4) In the controller of backend, set the environment value

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/")
public String messages(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("env", System.getenv("env");
    return "index";
}
```

But I failed at step 2, when trying to build with npm, I got an error message

> Template execution failed: ReferenceError: env is not defined

Is there any way to work around this problem or I have to take another approach?

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot comment yet: Below is how you reference the variables from model in Thymeleaf2.

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
     /*<![CDATA[*/
       var env = /*[[${env}]]*/ '';
     /*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I tried with the new syntax but got same result.

Comment: The attribute value "env" will only be populated at runtime not at compile time. You might have to default the value or pass the system variable as npm args